# sklearn import returning an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am new to machine learning and the sklearn package. when trying to import sklearn, I am getting an error saying it cannot find a DLL. I installed sklearn through pip, have un-installed everything including python and re-installed it all and still am having the same issue. only one version of python is installed on this machine. I am running python 3.6.1 and have visual studio 2017 community installed as well. All packages are up to date. The traceback is as follows. (removed username from all the paths)

code being ran:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import cross_validation, neighbors
import pandas as pd

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Public/Documents/Machine learning project/Classification/KNN.py", line 2, in <module>
    from sklearn import cross_validation, neighbors
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scipy import sparse
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\scipy\sparse\__init__.py", line 229, in <module>
    from .csr import *
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csr.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ._sparsetools import csr_tocsc, csr_tobsr, csr_count_blocks, get_csr_submatrix, csr_sample_values
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Comment: update your scipy

Comment: using a 64bit version of python, and I thought using PIP would install the right version of the package. but it appears, at least in my case, that it hasnt. I have now complied the binaries and installed that way and all is right in the world once again! Thanks millions Logan

Comment: Check your pip list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the version of python that you are using. Is it 64 bit or 32 bit? The only time I have seen that error is when there was a mismatch between the package type and the Python version.

If there is nothing wrong there you can try the following:

```
import imp
imp.find_module("sklearn")
```

This will tell you exactly what is being loaded and the path it is being loaded from.

If that is loading the correct package, I'd say try and install the package binary manually instead of going through pip. However I did just test it and saw it working on my system.

Answer (score 0):

I totally assent to using **from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate** but the process fails when you attempt to train the dataset. I will rather recommend importing the below library since your aim is to perform train_test_split functionality:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split as tts   
...
...
...
train_feats, test_feats, train_labels, test_labels = tts(features, labels, test_size=0.2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Although it is difficult to guess the issue you are experiencing based on what is provided, try the following:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
```